# Reset password screen when I turn on my MBP, what to do?

Tags: macos

I shutdown my MBP when it had 1% battery after that when I turn it on, I get this screen, anyone knows what to do? I know my password. When I choose forgot password it wants to restart to a recovery mode. I'm panicked to lose my data.

[image: a]

Comment: Looks like a similar question has been answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153040/why-did-os-x-ask-me-to-reset-my-password-at-startup). Does this help?